# How to write javascript on Drupal with drupal.behaviours

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-behaviors

I have a grid that contains two rows and three columns. Each column has a picture, a title, and a subtitle. All the pictures have the same class, let's say "image".I want the picture to change during hover. I have a div with the other image (the one that I want to show on hover) with the property display: none;

### This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row-1">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="view-field-image">
            <div class="field-content">
               <img class="image" src="../.." al="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="view-field-collapsed">
            <div class="field-content">
               <img class="collapsed" src="../.." al="">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2">
     </div>
     <div class="col-3">
     </div>
</div>
```

### This is the js code:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.hoverEffect = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $('.view-field-image .field-content', context)
        .once()
        .each( function () {
          $(this, context)
          .mouseenter( function () {
            console.log('enter');
            $('image', context).css('display', 'none');
            $('.collapsed', context).css('display', 'block');
          })
          .mouseleave( function () {
            console.log('leave');
            $('image', context).css('display', 'block');
            $('.collapsed', context).css('display', 'none');
          });
        });
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

I don't have the excepted result. When I hover over the picture all the pictures show the hidden picture with the collapsed class. Furthermore the picture with the class= "image" doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the javascript for a while, I realised you could simple do this with CSS, no Javascript needed.

You will just have to add a class to the columns, in the case of this example it is `image-col`.

```css
.image-col {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.image-col > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.image-col img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.image-col .view-field-image {
  z-index: 10;
}
.image-col .view-field-collapsed {
  z-index: 1;
}
.image-col:hover .view-field-image {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-1">
    <div class="col-1 image-col">
        <div class="view-field-image">
            <div class="field-content">
               <img class="image" src="https://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/09/google-logo-green2-1920.jpg" al="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="view-field-collapsed">
            <div class="field-content">
               <img class="collapsed" src="https://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/11/google-stars-reviews-rankings5-ss-1920.png" al="">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-2 image-col">
     </div>
     <div class="col-3 image-col">
     </div>
</div>
```

---

After posting this I saw that the problem is probably more than the way the context variable is being used.

But I am leaving the answer here on request of the OP.

**Original (wrong) answer**

You are using the context variable wrong.
context will be what jquery looks into to find an element.
eg.
`$('.something', context)`
jquery will search for ".something" inside of context.

Your code uses: 
`$('image', context).css('display', 'none');` but, as this is in a loop, you really only want the context to be the current element in the loop.
So your each loop should loop more like:

```
.each( function (index, element) {
  let $this = $(this);
  .mouseenter( function () {
    // Search for image in the current looping element.
    $('image', $this).css('display', 'none');
    // Search for all collapsed
    $('.collapsed', context).css('display', 'block');
  })
```

Answer (score -2):

```
       (function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

            Drupal.behaviors.YOURBEHAVIOR = {

                attach: function (context, settings) {

                    $('.YOURCLASS', context).on('YOUREVENT', function () {

                alert('TEST STRING...');  //Your javascript code...
                $('.YOURCLASS').addClass('ADD THE CLASSES HERE...');

                });

                }
            };
        })(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: How exactly is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @2pha why I can't see your answer anymore? It was very helpful!

Comment: sorry, I deleted it as I saw that the problem was more than what I had put in my answer. I will undelete it.

Comment: @2pha, i have given just a template about how the javascript will work with drupal behaviors where in alert section you can write your specific code.

Comment: @WasimKhan Your "template" adds nothing to what the OP already has.

Comment: @2pha, I added the code to make it easier how to use javascript inside drupal behaviors